# How to I create a custom toolbox with already existing stereotypes?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I was asked to create a toolbox with some stereotypes and some custom relationships. For example, "Functional Requirements" are "Affected by" "Usability Requirements". I noticed, however, that the former already exists in the "SysML 1.5 requirements" toolbox, so I would expect to include that one in my toolbox, create the one that doesn't exist and set the relationship.

Does this make sense in the EA context or should I create the custom toolbox fully from scratch?

Comment: I don't think you can re-use existing toolbox page definitions, but I might be wrong.

Comment: As Geert said. It's not too difficult to re-build a toolbox manually. Should take less than an hour.